# Prefer Using User Namespace Over System in Visual Studio Quick Actions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I have defined a type named `Component`, but there is already a type named that in `System.ComponentModel` namespace.

As a result when quick actions suggest to import a namespace for this type there are two choices.

It seems like `System` namespaces are given a priority as my namespace always comes in second in the suggestions.

Is there a way to have user defined namespaces at the top in quick actions, over the system ones?

[image: Visual Studio suggesting to use System.ComponentModel]

Comment: Maybe add `using Component = Domain.Core.Component;`, so you don't have to choose?

Comment: To be clear this is a question for convenience, I want to avoid clicking down-arrow each time I need to import this namespace. Having to write `using Component = Domain.Core.Component;` is even more work, unless it can be done on assembly level?

Comment: I’m afraid, you can’t change the order of the list which is provided by Intellisense. Intellisense will default to have system’s namespaces on the top of the list. If you’d like to customize the order of the intellisense’s list, I suggest you directly suggest this feature to VS Product Team from Help > Send Feedback > Suggest a Feature…

Comment: Requested feature here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1090752/prefer-using-users-namespaces-over-systems-in-visu.html